# Replacing DMD's kernel32.lib to include missing functions

Tags: windows, d, dmd

I'm using dmd 2.054 and optlink 8.00.12 on Windows 7.

The following program:

```
pragma(lib, "kernel32.lib");
extern(Windows) {
    uint LocaleNameToLCID(const(wchar)*, int);
}

void main() {
    auto us = LocaleNameToLCID("en-US", 0);
}
```

Gives an error when compiling:

```
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _LocaleNameToLCID@8
```

But if I try to replace kernel32.lib, I get many errors:

```
implib /system kernel32.lib \Windows\system32\kernel32.dll

 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _LocaleNameToLCID@8
c:\dmd\windows\bin\..\lib\phobos.lib(dmain2)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _LocalFree@4
c:\dmd\windows\bin\..\lib\phobos.lib(dmain2)
(... snip ...)
```

Looking at the original lib and the implib created for `LocalFree` shows there are differences, but I'm not sure what that means (some special characters are missing from this output)

```
---------- IMPLIB
    LocalFree
_LocalFreekernel32.dll  LocalFree
_K32GetPerformanceInfo!_LocalFree!Z
_MoveFileExA!É_QueryPerformanceCounter!c_ReadConsoleOutputA!Ó
_LocalFreeZ


---------- DMD'S
    LocalFree
_LocalFree@4KERNEL32.dll    LocalFree
_LocalFree@4}
```

Any idea how I can use the new kernel32.lib in my programs to avoid missing symbols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind..

I had also tried using `coffimplib` earlier without success, but now it works. No idea what I've done earlier.

So my solution has been to download the windows sdk and using `coffimplib` on the libraries I need.

Sorry for the spam. If someone could tell me why `implib` doesn't work I'll accept that answer.